# Getting started with Dynamic CRM 2011 Microsoft?

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm mapped to India Microsoft Solutions Service line and I'm told I will be working on Microsoft Dynamic CRM in projects.

My manager and mentor told me start reading .NET (C# and ASP.net) in depth so it will help you
to master Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2011 application.

After goggling I found .NET is not really necessary to start learning Ms Dynamic CRM 2011.

I'm stuck in a situation, can anybody tell me first i should start .NET or Directly hands on Dynamic CRM 2011 application?

Comment: Hi i have explained how to integrate CRM with web-api in this link please check this out http://grandhah.blogspot.in/2016/01/integrating-mycrosoft-dynamic-crm-with.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go through the Dynamics CRM 2011 [Developer Training videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/DynamicsCRM2011) to get an introduction and then start playing with the application to get a good feel for what you can customize. Understand that you're not building an application, you're basically creating a bundle of everything that's changing from your starting base. The related Developer Training kit can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23416).

When you're up to speed a bit and looking for code samples (or you get stuck) I'd recommend always referring to the official [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24004).

Answer (score 2):

I think if you are going to deal with MS Dynamics CRM, you should immediately start reading about CRM itself. [Here](http://rc.crm.dynamics.com/rc/regcont/en_us/OPhighlights.aspx) you can find some resources. e.g you can start reading from [customization](http://rc.crm.dynamics.com/rc/regcont/en_us/OP/articles/thingstoknowaboutcustomization.aspx)
But your manager is right, if you are going to work as a developer, you will need knowledge in Internet Explorer DOM, Javascript, and .Net. Here you can find [training materials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm/bb456480) for MS Dynamics CRM developers.

Comment: one of the links you posted was for CRM 4.0. It might not be helpful since he asked about CRM 2011 :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to undertand the matrials that *paramosh* posted:

First: create a Windows-Live account and login to 
[crm.dynamics.com](http://crm.dynamics.com) create an online Demo Organization, this organization is 30 days trial.
You can implement and try everything on CRM during this period.

Important: Before, going deep into the development of CRM, you have to undertand how Customer-relationship-Management works first. Marketing campaigns, opportunities, sales and more.
Before going to the second step, you have to ensure that you understand the how concepts of Customer-relationship-Managment bussiness work.

Second: After practicing on CRM, [download the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24004), and you'll find many samples for customzing as a developer.

Third: Read the .chm file carefuly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if you will be doing any type of integration work into crm using the api?
By this i mean add update delete entities or custom entities in Crm?

If so a good place to start would be to take a deep dive into the MSCRM SDK. My advice is use your class browser to dissect it. As you will come to realize later that there are inconsistencies in the api and by then you will know how the engine works.

Get to understand the discovery and organizational proxies then move on to understanding the entities (eg. contact, incident, custom entities, extended properties. etc.).
Relationships between entities are really important get to know how to construct object tree and how to persist it to the organizational proxy.

Have a read over authentication and how crm handles integration scenarios.
Then there is client-side scripting model supported by MSCRM 2011 if you will be doing html javascript integration. If you planning to do a silverlight integration, meaning creating a silverlight component uploading at as a resource and the plugin integrating into crm backend there is the organizational proxy and the restful odata proxy you choose which to use. I personally prefer creating an adapter for the organizational and discovery proxy as having a resilient backend requires good logging and profiling framework. you will be needing this to debug integration errors that can you can easily find when errors are being caught and logged. You will also need to decide to use the early or late bound datatype model for integration my choice is early bound.

Go here for a good start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327971.aspx

Cheers
Rustin